# Add a eps file or pdf file to my report - MATLAB Report Generator

Tags: matlab, reporting

I'm trying to make my report using the Matlab Report Generator.

I want to include some graphs that are in PDF format and others in eps. I've tried to use this code:

```
% Insert the image into the report
imgStyle = {ScaleToFit(true)};
img1 = Image(which('RBC_baseline_IRF_eps_z.eps'));
img1.Style = imgStyle;

img2 = Image(which('rrga.pdf'));
img2.Style = imgStyle;

lot = Table({img1, ' ', img2});

lot.entry(1,1).Style = {Width('3.2in'), Height('3in')};
lot.entry(1,2).Style = {Width('.2in'), Height('3in')};
lot.entry(1,3).Style = {Width('3.2in'), Height('3in')};

lot.Style = {ResizeToFitContents(false), Width('100%')};

add(rpt, lot);
br3 = PageBreak();
```

but it does not work. Could you help me?

Thanks in advance!